# Obj can not be resolved

Tags: java, ip

```
public class IPAddress {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String[] cmd = {"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe","/c","start"};

        try {        
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runtime.exec(cmd);

        } catch (java.io.IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        String release = "ipconfig /release";
        String output1 = obj.executeCommand(release);
        String renew = "ipconfig /renew";
        String output2 = obj.executeCommand(renew);

        System.out.println(output1);
        System.out.println(output2);
    }
}
```

I am making an IP Changer, and on "String output1" and "String output2" i get an error that says obj can not be resolved. I have tried resolving this but to no evail

Comment: where did you define `obj`?

Comment: What is 'obj''? Where did you create it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `obj` object. Since there isn't any `obj` object in your main method, it cannot find it. You need to create that object inside main method.

Comment: … or outside, at class level.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code have you created a **obj** object. This is why you are getting an error from the compiler, explaining that it does not know where it has come from.